# Autoplay images from SDCard

Tags: android, image, sd-card, autoplay

Sorry Guys for all the vague questions. this is what i want to do. I want my app to randomly play images from SdCard and I want no user input after app is started. I have read lot of sdcard post but this is not same question. if this is possible please let me know how i go about this. I do not want any user input once the app is started it just plays images from sdcard. Thank you for your help. by the way i am trying to implement this using android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a slide show of images from your sdcard have a look at  http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/image-slide-show.html. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I follow the tutorial but did not work. It breaks when it starts. here is my logcat error.

Comment: hi 
i tried it and it works too. the only problem is that when i try to rotate my phone to landscape view it crashes any solution. one more thing when i updated my sd card folder by putting some more images. it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Get the image paths into the sdcard and pass it to the gallery.
You can follow this link for few more information http://raivoratsep.com/114/android-gallery-tutorial-working-example/

suppose you get the path name as

```
String pathName = "/sdcard/images/abc.jpg";
```

You can set the image to the image view as

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);
```

hope this may help you

Comment: That's my pleasure.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi I am trying to work with this code, but it is giving me error when i set pathName to R.id.imageView1. and i do not know if this is the right way to set content view.

Comment: you need to set the image to the image view.
You are getting an error because Pathname is a string and R.id.imageView1 is an int.
you no need to set the pathName to R.id.imageView1 instead use Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);
and set it using the img.setImageDrawable(drawable) in the getView()

Comment: Did you get the paths of images from the sdcard?

Comment: well did you get the path of the images from the gallery.Say this please

Comment: I am not sure. I thought I set my own path like you have given example above. can we also set multiple paths.

Comment: ok i tried for an alternative(without gallery) and i will post it soon

Answer (score 0):

try creating another layout-land folder with the same xml file as in the layout folder.
This will be used as the layout when the mobile is in the landscape mode.
And to prevent crashing try to use

```
System.gc();
```

in the ondestroy()
And i didnt find any difficulty by adding new images.
They work fine for me.